# Finding user names with particular characters in their last name

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

In Oracle SQL, I wish to find all user names,whose Last name contains some specific Characters like ('Z','X','D','F') Or contains Some Range of Characters from 'A-F'.

I tried this:

```
 SELECT user_last_name
    FROM   userbase
    WHERE  user_last_name LIKE '%A%' OR user_last_name LIKE '%F%' .
```

So How can I go about it.

And I written facebook in question although its not directly related to it,because,its the example given by my sir.

**UPDATE:** I tried the above code,it works with so many OR's, but How can we define some range to search for like IN('Z','X','D','F') or IN ('A-F')

Comment: posting the exception might help. There aren't that many psychics on stackoverflow.

Comment: you mean I post what the error Im getting

Comment: @Justin_cave :Thankyou for the edits and previous query also. And I had sent you a LinkedIn request,hope to get accept from you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a recent version of Oracle, you should be able to use regular expressions

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1   select first_name, last_name
  2     from employees
  3*   where regexp_like( last_name, 'Z|X|D|[A-F]' )
SQL> /

FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME
-------------------- -------------------------
Ellen                Abel
Sundar               Ande
Mozhe                Atkinson
David                Austin
Hermann              Baer
Shelli               Baida
Amit                 Banda
Elizabeth            Bates
Sarah                Bell
David                Bernstein
Laura                Bissot
Harrison             Bloom
Alexis               Bull
Anthony              Cabrio
Gerald               Cambrault
Nanette              Cambrault
John                 Chen
Kelly                Chung
Karen                Colmenares
Curtis               Davies
Lex                  De Haan
Julia                Dellinger
Jennifer             Dilly
Louise               Doran
Bruce                Ernst
Alberto              Errazuriz
Britney              Everett
Daniel               Faviet
Pat                  Fay
Kevin                Feeney
Jean                 Fleaur
Tayler               Fox
Adam                 Fripp
Samuel               McCain
Allan                McEwen
Donald               OConnell
Eleni                Zlotkey

37 rows selected.
```

If you want the search to be case-insensitive

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1   select first_name, last_name
  2     from employees
  3*   where regexp_like( last_name, 'Z|X|D|[A-F]', 'i' )
SQL> /

FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME
-------------------- -------------------------
Ellen                Abel
Sundar               Ande
Mozhe                Atkinson
David                Austin
Hermann              Baer
Shelli               Baida
Amit                 Banda
Elizabeth            Bates
Sarah                Bell
David                Bernstein
Laura                Bissot
Harrison             Bloom
Alexis               Bull
Anthony              Cabrio
Gerald               Cambrault
Nanette              Cambrault
John                 Chen
Kelly                Chung
Karen                Colmenares
Curtis               Davies
Lex                  De Haan
<<snip>>
Matthew              Weiss
Jennifer             Whalen
Eleni                Zlotkey

93 rows selected.
```

Comment: @Justin_cave: From your answers,I see everything is possible in Oracle,which I was unaware of the power of oracle platform.

Comment: and ,what is 'i' in syntax of regexp_like(); And how you have already have dummy data to test any command,because,for practice,I'm also in need of that.

Comment: @Demla - The 'i' as the second argument to `REGEXP_LIKE` specifies that you want a case insensitive search.  When you install an Oracle database, you have the option of installing various sample schemas.  The `SCOTT` and `HR` schemas are two of the more commonly used schemas for sample code.  I'm using the `EMPLOYEES` table in the `HR` schema for this example.

Comment: THANKS I got it in the list of tables, by using all_tables list in oracle.

Comment: BUT , I Tried this A-F, it doesn't works,where if  any of A TO F characters present, then it should return those last names

Comment: @Demla - Sorry, I forgot to enclose the A-F in brackets

Comment: can you suggest some useful resource to understand functions like TRUNC and all in easy way.

Comment: @Demla - That's getting a bit off-topic for this discussion.  If you have additional questions, please feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSTR to test whether characters exist in your field, like so:

```
SELECT
  user_last_name
FROM
  userbase
WHERE 0 < INSTR(user_last_name,'A')
   or 0 < INSTR(user_last_name,'B')
   ...repeat for each character you want to test for...
```